# Sacar Mínimo y Máximo de registros

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Actualmente estoy realizando una consulta y tengo el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como digo en la imagen lo que deseo es que en **todos** los registros se muestren los datos que estoy pidiendo pero no encuentro la forma. A continuación muestro el `SQL`:

```
DECLARE @Fecha DATE ='2020-03-11' 
DECLARE @FechaInicial DATETIME = dbo.fnConvertirFechaDatetime(@Fecha,'I'),
            @FechaFinal DATETIME = dbo.fnConvertirFechaDatetime(@Fecha,'F')

SELECT 
            RazonSocial,
            Nit,
            IdComputador,
            FechaComprobante            = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),FechaComprobante,111),
            NumeroInicialTransacciones  = MIN(Numerofactura),
            NumeroFinalTransacciones    = MAX(Numerofactura),
            CodigoCuenta,
            Descripcion,
            SerialComputador,
            CodigoIPS,
            NombreIPS,
            Usuario,
            NombreUsuario,
            NumeroRegistroRealizados    = COUNT(DISTINCT Numerofactura),
            VentaEfectivo               = SUM(VentaEfectivo),
            VentaCredito                = SUM(VentaCredito),
            ValorTotalRegistrado        = SUM(ValorTotalRegistrado),
            Exentas                     = SUM(Exentas),
            Excluidas                   = SUM(Excluidas),
            Iva                         = SUM(Iva),
            Descuento                   = SUM(Descuento),
            Letra                       = SUM(Letra),
            NotaDebito                  = SUM(NotaDebito),
            NotaCredito                 = SUM(NotaCredito),
            Abono                       = SUM(Abono),
            Deposito                    = SUM(Deposito),
            Subtotal                    = SUM(Subtotal)
    FROM  (
        SELECT 
            RazonSocial             = seriales.r_social,
            Nit                     = seriales.nit,
            IdComputador            = usuario.IdComputadorAsignado,
            FechaComprobante        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Fecha,111),
            Numerofactura           = (sis_maes.prefijo+sis_maes.NumeroFactura),
            CodigoCuenta            = cuentasUFView.cuenta,
            Descripcion             = cuentascont_zeus.descripcion,
            SerialComputador        = usuario.SerialComputador,
            CodigoIPS               = puntoAtencion.codigo,
            NombreIPS               = puntoAtencion.nombre,
            Usuario                 = usuario.usuario,
            NombreUsuario           = usuario.nombre,
            VentaEfectivo           = ISNULL((CASE WHEN contratos.FormasDePago='CD' THEN sis_deta.total ELSE 0 END),0),
            VentaCredito            = ISNULL((CASE WHEN contratos.FormasDePago='CR' THEN sis_deta.total ELSE 0 END),0),
            ValorTotalRegistrado    = ISNULL(sis_deta.total,0),
            Exentas                 = 0,
            Excluidas               = 0,
            Iva                     = ISNULL(sis_deta.ValorIva,0),
            Descuento               = 0,
            Letra                   = 0,
            NotaDebito              = 0,
            NotaCredito             = 0,
            Abono                   = 0,
            Deposito                = 0,
            Subtotal                = ISNULL(sis_deta.total+sis_deta.ValorIva,0)
        FROM sis_maes
            INNER JOIN seriales ON seriales.id = sis_maes.id_sede
            INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.cedula = sis_maes.cod_usuario
            INNER JOIN sis_deta ON sis_deta.estudio = sis_maes.con_estudio
            INNER JOIN cuentasUFView ON cuentasUFView.id_ufc = sis_deta.id_cuenta
            INNER JOIN cuentascont_zeus ON cuentascont_zeus.cuenta =  cuentasUFView.cuenta COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
            INNER JOIN puntoAtencion ON puntoAtencion.id = sis_maes.puntoAtencion
            INNER JOIN contratos ON contratos.codigo = sis_maes.contrato
        WHERE 
            sis_maes.nro_factura > 0 AND 
            sis_maes.estado='C' AND
            contratos.tipo_contrato<>1 AND
            sis_maes.fecha_egreso BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
        UNION
        SELECT 
            RazonSocial             = seriales.r_social,
            Nit                     = seriales.nit,
            IdComputador            = usuario.IdComputadorAsignado,
            FechaComprobante        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Fecha,111),
            NumeroFactura           = (pagos.prefijo+pagos.NumeroFactura),
            CodigoCuenta            = sis_tipo.cuenta,
            Descripcion             = cuentascont_zeus.descripcion,
            SerialComputador        = usuario.SerialComputador,
            CodigoIPS               = puntoAtencion.codigo,
            NombreIPS               = puntoAtencion.nombre,
            Usuario                 = usuario.usuario,
            NombreUsuario           = usuario.nombre,
            VentaEfectivo           = ISNULL(pagos.valor,0),
            VentaCredito            = 0,
            ValorTotalRegistrado    = 0,
            Exentas                 = 0,
            Excluidas               = 0,
            Iva                     = 0,
            Descuento               = 0,
            Letra                   = 0,
            NotaDebito              = 0,
            NotaCredito             = 0,
            Abono                   = 0,
            Deposito                = 0,
            Subtotal                = ISNULL(pagos.valor,0)
        FROM sis_maes
            INNER JOIN seriales ON seriales.id = sis_maes.id_sede
            INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.cedula = sis_maes.cod_usuario
            INNER JOIN puntoAtencion ON puntoAtencion.id = sis_maes.puntoAtencion
            INNER JOIN pagos ON pagos.con_estudio = sis_maes.con_estudio
            INNER JOIN sis_tipo ON sis_tipo.id = pagos.fuente
            INNER JOIN cuentascont_zeus ON cuentascont_zeus.cuenta =  sis_tipo.cuenta COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
        WHERE 
            pagos.NumeroFactura IS NOT NULL AND
            pagos.activo = 1 AND
            pagos.fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
    ) Resolucion
    GROUP BY Resolucion.RazonSocial, Resolucion.Nit, Resolucion.IdComputador, Resolucion.FechaComprobante, Resolucion.CodigoCuenta, Resolucion.Descripcion,
        Resolucion.SerialComputador, Resolucion.CodigoIPS, Resolucion.NombreIPS, Resolucion.Usuario, Resolucion.NombreUsuario
    ORDER BY RazonSocial, NombreUsuario, CodigoIPS, CodigoCuenta
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás agrupando por `CodigoCuenta` y `Descripcion` pero esas columnas tienen valores distintos. Tal vez puede pasar con otras columnas también.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de como mantener los distintos valores, pero obtener máximos y mínimos de ciertas columnas. Claro, que todo depende de las reglas de tu información para agrupar.

```
DECLARE @Fecha DATE ='2020-03-11' 
DECLARE @FechaInicial DATETIME = dbo.fnConvertirFechaDatetime(@Fecha,'I'),
            @FechaFinal DATETIME = dbo.fnConvertirFechaDatetime(@Fecha,'F')
SELECT 
            RazonSocial,
            Nit,
            IdComputador,
            FechaComprobante            ,
            NumeroInicialTransacciones  = MIN(NumeroInicialTransacciones) OVER( PARTITION BY RazonSocial, Nit, IdComputador, FechaComprobante),
            NumeroFinalTransacciones    = MAX(NumeroFinalTransacciones) OVER( PARTITION BY RazonSocial, Nit, IdComputador, FechaComprobante),
            CodigoCuenta,
            Descripcion,
            SerialComputador,
            CodigoIPS,
            NombreIPS,
            Usuario,
            NombreUsuario,
            NumeroRegistroRealizados    ,
            VentaEfectivo               ,
            VentaCredito                ,
            ValorTotalRegistrado        ,
            Exentas                     ,
            Excluidas                   ,
            Iva                         ,
            Descuento                   ,
            Letra                       ,
            NotaDebito                  ,
            NotaCredito                 ,
            Abono                       ,
            Deposito                    ,
            Subtotal                    
FROM( 
    SELECT 
                RazonSocial,
                Nit,
                IdComputador,
                FechaComprobante            = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),FechaComprobante,111),
                NumeroInicialTransacciones  = MIN(Numerofactura),
                NumeroFinalTransacciones    = MAX(Numerofactura),
                CodigoCuenta,
                Descripcion,
                SerialComputador,
                CodigoIPS,
                NombreIPS,
                Usuario,
                NombreUsuario,
                NumeroRegistroRealizados    = COUNT(DISTINCT Numerofactura),
                VentaEfectivo               = SUM(VentaEfectivo),
                VentaCredito                = SUM(VentaCredito),
                ValorTotalRegistrado        = SUM(ValorTotalRegistrado),
                Exentas                     = SUM(Exentas),
                Excluidas                   = SUM(Excluidas),
                Iva                         = SUM(Iva),
                Descuento                   = SUM(Descuento),
                Letra                       = SUM(Letra),
                NotaDebito                  = SUM(NotaDebito),
                NotaCredito                 = SUM(NotaCredito),
                Abono                       = SUM(Abono),
                Deposito                    = SUM(Deposito),
                Subtotal                    = SUM(Subtotal)
        FROM  (
            SELECT 
                RazonSocial             = seriales.r_social,
                Nit                     = seriales.nit,
                IdComputador            = usuario.IdComputadorAsignado,
                FechaComprobante        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Fecha,111),
                Numerofactura           = (sis_maes.prefijo+sis_maes.NumeroFactura),
                CodigoCuenta            = cuentasUFView.cuenta,
                Descripcion             = cuentascont_zeus.descripcion,
                SerialComputador        = usuario.SerialComputador,
                CodigoIPS               = puntoAtencion.codigo,
                NombreIPS               = puntoAtencion.nombre,
                Usuario                 = usuario.usuario,
                NombreUsuario           = usuario.nombre,
                VentaEfectivo           = ISNULL((CASE WHEN contratos.FormasDePago='CD' THEN sis_deta.total ELSE 0 END),0),
                VentaCredito            = ISNULL((CASE WHEN contratos.FormasDePago='CR' THEN sis_deta.total ELSE 0 END),0),
                ValorTotalRegistrado    = ISNULL(sis_deta.total,0),
                Exentas                 = 0,
                Excluidas               = 0,
                Iva                     = ISNULL(sis_deta.ValorIva,0),
                Descuento               = 0,
                Letra                   = 0,
                NotaDebito              = 0,
                NotaCredito             = 0,
                Abono                   = 0,
                Deposito                = 0,
                Subtotal                = ISNULL(sis_deta.total+sis_deta.ValorIva,0)
            FROM sis_maes
                INNER JOIN seriales ON seriales.id = sis_maes.id_sede
                INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.cedula = sis_maes.cod_usuario
                INNER JOIN sis_deta ON sis_deta.estudio = sis_maes.con_estudio
                INNER JOIN cuentasUFView ON cuentasUFView.id_ufc = sis_deta.id_cuenta
                INNER JOIN cuentascont_zeus ON cuentascont_zeus.cuenta =  cuentasUFView.cuenta COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
                INNER JOIN puntoAtencion ON puntoAtencion.id = sis_maes.puntoAtencion
                INNER JOIN contratos ON contratos.codigo = sis_maes.contrato
            WHERE 
                sis_maes.nro_factura > 0 AND 
                sis_maes.estado='C' AND
                contratos.tipo_contrato<>1 AND
                sis_maes.fecha_egreso BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
            UNION
            SELECT 
                RazonSocial             = seriales.r_social,
                Nit                     = seriales.nit,
                IdComputador            = usuario.IdComputadorAsignado,
                FechaComprobante        = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@Fecha,111),
                NumeroFactura           = (pagos.prefijo+pagos.NumeroFactura),
                CodigoCuenta            = sis_tipo.cuenta,
                Descripcion             = cuentascont_zeus.descripcion,
                SerialComputador        = usuario.SerialComputador,
                CodigoIPS               = puntoAtencion.codigo,
                NombreIPS               = puntoAtencion.nombre,
                Usuario                 = usuario.usuario,
                NombreUsuario           = usuario.nombre,
                VentaEfectivo           = ISNULL(pagos.valor,0),
                VentaCredito            = 0,
                ValorTotalRegistrado    = 0,
                Exentas                 = 0,
                Excluidas               = 0,
                Iva                     = 0,
                Descuento               = 0,
                Letra                   = 0,
                NotaDebito              = 0,
                NotaCredito             = 0,
                Abono                   = 0,
                Deposito                = 0,
                Subtotal                = ISNULL(pagos.valor,0)
            FROM sis_maes
                INNER JOIN seriales ON seriales.id = sis_maes.id_sede
                INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.cedula = sis_maes.cod_usuario
                INNER JOIN puntoAtencion ON puntoAtencion.id = sis_maes.puntoAtencion
                INNER JOIN pagos ON pagos.con_estudio = sis_maes.con_estudio
                INNER JOIN sis_tipo ON sis_tipo.id = pagos.fuente
                INNER JOIN cuentascont_zeus ON cuentascont_zeus.cuenta =  sis_tipo.cuenta COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
            WHERE 
                pagos.NumeroFactura IS NOT NULL AND
                pagos.activo = 1 AND
                pagos.fecha BETWEEN @FechaInicial AND @FechaFinal
        ) Resolucion
        GROUP BY Resolucion.RazonSocial, Resolucion.Nit, Resolucion.IdComputador, Resolucion.FechaComprobante, Resolucion.CodigoCuenta, Resolucion.Descripcion,
            Resolucion.SerialComputador, Resolucion.CodigoIPS, Resolucion.NombreIPS, Resolucion.Usuario, Resolucion.NombreUsuario
    )R
    ORDER BY RazonSocial, NombreUsuario, CodigoIPS, CodigoCuenta
```

Comment: Funciono para mí, lo único por corregir es en vez de NumeroFactura en los  MIN y MAX debería ser NumeroInicialTransacciones  y NumeroFinalTransacciones, quedando así:

`NumeroInicialTransacciones  = MIN(NumeroInicialTransacciones) OVER( PARTITION BY RazonSocial, Nit, IdComputador, FechaComprobante),
            NumeroFinalTransacciones    = MAX(NumeroFinalTransacciones) OVER( PARTITION BY RazonSocial, Nit, IdComputador, FechaComprobante),`

Del resto excelente, agradecido por tu ayuda.

Comment: Tienes razón. Ya lo edité por si alguien más requiere el ejemplo.